# How to exclude binding if ng-content given?

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm trying to create a custom primeNG button with its own ng-content. The goal is that if the content is given, it should be used in place of the standard pButton label binding.

This is the basic code that I've come up with for this component:

```html
<button pButton [label]="label">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</button>
```

This of course will always show both the label and the ng-content provided in the button. I want to see the label only if content is not provided.

I've gone down a few rabbit holes on this one, including trying to integrate ngIf, using ViewChild to check if the ng-content exists, etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi  S. Thompson have any of my answers works for you ? 

Comment: Yes, I believe that both answers get me much closer to what I am looking for. I noticed though that projected content of any complexity becomes an issue. For instance, if I create this:

```html
<c-btn>
   <h1>Some Text</h1>
</c-btn>
```

then what I receive is a button with content that is mangled by Angular. Is there a way around that?

Comment: there is always a way  check my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get a reference for the container with viewchild and check the if the elemnt has content already or not and base of that you ethier set the passed label value or the projected value the custom component will look like this

the custome component will look like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'c-btn',
  templateUrl: './btn.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./btn.component.css']
})
export class BtnComponent  {

  @Input('label') staticLabel : string= "";

  @ViewChild('content') projectedLabel: ElementRef;

  get label () :string{
    return  this.projectedLabel.nativeElement.innerHTML.trim() || this.staticLabel
  }

}
```

template

```
<button pButton [label]="label" ></button>

<div #content style="display:none">
    <ng-content ></ng-content>
</div>
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-startup-ymbuyb)

> puting `ng-content` outside the button elemnt make it easer to check if it
>   's got a value or not,
>   another reasone why you have to put `ng-content` outside the button
>   elemnt it related to primeng , **pButton** has some kind of structure in
>   order the button will view as intated so in both cases you need
>   use property binding with the label property

*another way*

this could be the simplest solution by using template variable and check if the element has a content or not.

*custome element*

```
<button pButton [label]="content.innerHTML || label" ></button>

<div #content style="display:none">
    <ng-content ></ng-content>
</div>
```

*component*

```
export class BtnComponent  {

  @Input() label : string= "";  
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-startup-d1mheg)

**Updated⚡⚡**

this will support projection as html element not just as text to the button by update span inside the button

*component*

```
  @Input('label') label : string= "";

  @ViewChild('content') projectedLabel: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('btn') button: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    if (this.projectedLabel.nativeElement.innerHTML){
       const elm = this.button.nativeElement.querySelector('span');
        elm.innerHTML =  this.projectedLabel.nativeElement.innerHTML;
    }
  }
```

*template*

```
<button pButton [label]="label" #btn></button>

<div #content style="display:none">
    <ng-content ></ng-content>
</div>
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-startup-tyf9in)